# How can I execute code before eval with jQuery.getScript

Tags: jquery

Is there a hook to execute code before eval is called in [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) of `$.getScript()`:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
    // code to execute before query
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is I need to execute after receive and before eval.